# Qt Grid with QgraphicsItems drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt, grid, qgraphicsitem

so I'm currently making a scrabble game

and I have a QGraphicsScene with a grid on it. The grid is made out of tiles which are custom QGraphicsItems containing variables.

Now I also have another custom QGraphicsItem, which are the characters that should be placed on the tiles (so the other QGraphicsItems). How can I make the user put the characters on the tiles with some kind of drag and drop mechanism?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user is using the mouse to move characters, when they release the mouse after dragging a character, search for the nearest grid item position and then animate the tile to that position, probably with QGraphicsItemAnimation.

Comment: and that search function should be part of the scene?

Comment: That depends on the overall design of your class hierarchy. Ideally I'd try to keep the QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView as clean as possible and just use it as an interface between user input and other classes, but you could put it as a function of the scene as it's really a helper function based on the items in the scene.

Comment: You don't really need to "search" for the nearest grid item, it's just a matter of calling `QGraphicsView::itemAt(const QPoint&)` with the mouse position (when the mouse button is released) as the argument and it will return the grid item.

Comment: Same thing, itemAt searches for the nearest item at that point. That's like saying you don't need to print text, just call printf!

Comment: If you read Cédric's first comment it appears that he's not aware of the existence of the `itemAt` function and that's why thought it would be a good idea to mention it. In your comment you also seem to suggest that he should implement a search function instead of using what's already available.

Comment: @DanielHedberg that's not how it was in my mind when I wrote it, but if that's how you interpret it, fair enough.